# How do I create a prepared statement?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, prepared-statement

I cannot find any documentation that adequately explains how to use them. How to you retrieve variables from a query and use them and what do the parameters mean to the queries? I want to make my website safe from sql injection and I don't have a clue how to get the following code optimized for safety. I understand how sql injection works, I just don't know how to create the prepared statements or retrieve queries.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

$tempProf = $_POST["professor"];
$tempProfArray = explode("=",$tempProf);
$prof = $tempProfArray[1];

$tempName = $_POST["name"];
$tempNameArray = explode("=",$tempName);
$name = $tempNameArray[1];

$tempNum = $_POST["number"];
$tempNumArray = explode("=",$tempNum);
$num = $tempNumArray[1];

$tempSec = $_POST["section"];
$tempSecArray = explode("=",$tempSec);
$section = $tempSecArray[1];

$tempCat = $_POST["category"];
$tempCatArray = explode("=",$tempCat);
$category = $tempCatArray[1];

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","*******","******");

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM professors where id='$prof'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);



if(empty($prof) || empty($name) || empty($num) || empty($section) || empty($category))
{
    echo "emptyField";
}
elseif(!is_numeric($num)  || !is_numeric($section))
{
    echo "NaN";
}
elseif(empty($row))
{
    mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO classes (className, classNumber, section, classCategory)
    VALUES ('$name','$num','$section','$category')");

    $classTemp = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id FROM classes where className='$name' and classNumber='$num' and section ='$section'");
    $classTempArray = mysqli_fetch_array($classTemp);
    $classId = $classTempArray['id'];

    mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO professors (name, classes) VALUES ('$prof','$classId')");

    $profTemp = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id FROM professors where name='$prof'");
    $profTempArray = mysqli_fetch_array($profTemp);
    $profId = $profTempArray['id'];
    mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE classes SET professor = '$profId' WHERE id = '$classId'");
    echo "success";
}
else
{
    $profName = $row['id'];
    mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO classes (professor, className, classNumber, section, classCategory)
    VALUES ('$prof', '$name','$num','$section','$category')");
    echo "success";
}

?>
```

Comment: This is hard to find? [PHP Mysqli_Stmt::Prepare Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.prepare.php) basically has one from start to finish.

Comment: "Jason", I checked your link and it is very comprehensive. I kept arriving at a different php prepared statement manual that didn't help. I assumed they were the same. Thank you.

Comment: "I cannot find any documentation...". I will believe that statement only if you replace "can" with "refuse to".

Comment: Replace being helpful and understanding with making a useless comment on a 2 year old question with no votes because you are unhappy with your life and you have @MadPhysicist

Answer (score 1):

In general, something like this will suffice (note that I use the object orientated way of accessing connections, not procedural like you)

```
$stmt = $con->prepare( 'INSERT INTO classes (professor, className, classNumber, section, classCategory) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' )
$stmt->bind_param( 'ssiss', $prof, $name, $num, $section, $category );
$stmt->execute();
```

In this case I am assuming that everything but $num is a string, and $num is an integer.

Here is the relevant doc for binding params: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: Ok, that helps a lot. How would I retrieve the results from a query where I select multiple rows?

Comment: And this is going to sound dumb but is `->` some sort of operator or is it just part of statements like `$con->prepare` simply as part of the naming scheme?

Comment: It runs a method belonging to the variable. The long way would be: mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ssiss', $prof, $name, $num, $section, $category );

Comment: Ok, that makes a lot more sense.

Answer (score -1):

```
$sql="SELECT id FROM classes WEHERE className=? AND classNumber=? AND section =?";

$stmt =$con->prepare($sql);

$stmt->execute(array($name,$num,$ection));

//you can apply this for other queries
```

Comment: Although the code is appreciated, it should always have an accompanying explanation. This doesn't have to be long, but it is expected.